# UIRefreshControl control spins forever after inserting new row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a `UITableView`, that on the delegate of the `UIViewController` that adds a new item, inserts the row.  The row gets correctly inserted.

However, the `UIRefreshControl` on the UITableView will not go away when dragging the `UITableView` after that.

```
extension FeedViewController: AddPostDelegate {
    func didAddPost(_ userPost: UserPost) {
        self.postsWrapper?.posts.insert(PostWrapper(type: PostType.user(userPost)), at: 0)
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [
            IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
            ], with: .automatic)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
        self.refresher.endRefreshing()//Does nothing
    }
}
```

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
refresher = UIRefreshControl()
tableView.addSubview(refresher)
refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didDragScrollView), for: .valueChanged)
refresher.layer.zPosition = -1//otherwise in front of the header cell when refreshing (iOS 9.2)
```

If I do not go to another view first than come back before attempting to pull for refresh, it always hangs spinning forever.

EDIT:
It looks like the `UIRefreshControl` is no longer calling the target function AFTER I add a post.

Any ideas on why this may be occurring?  How to fix that?

Comment: Remark unrelated to your question. You're adding refresh control as a subview, and perfectly fine if that's what you need. But in case you're not aware, there is a `UITableView`  (`UIScrollView`) property `refreshControl` which can be used out of the box.

Comment: @AuRis that is only 10.0 or newer, so for supporting users still, for some reason, below that - then you cannot use that.  According to my app's users statistics, there are still about 8% of users on iOS 9

Comment: @KaylaGalway if you are referring to DispatchQueue.main.async, then yes, I tried that

Comment: @daredevil1234 sure, makes sense if you're still supporting iOS 9. Regarding refresh, are you initiating it with a "pull to refresh" action or do you call `refresher.beginRefreshing()` somewhere?

Comment: @AuRis I am actually pulling to refresh.  The refresh works correctly before adding a post, but after adding a post it does not.  Based on what im debugging, it looks like the RefreshControl no longer calls its' target function after that

Comment: Do you anywhere in your code call `beginRefreshing()`? It is very strange that you seeing this behaviour. When refreshing begins and is not ended, then the selector doesn't get called.

Comment: Does your `postsWrapper?.posts.insert()` do anything with the `tableView`?

Comment: @AuRis no, that is just the data, it's basically a wrapper around an array of information, but the wrapper includes more information, such as if there is more information, needs to be refreshed, etc

Comment: @AuRis can you submit an answer about beginRefreshing being called manually somewhere else?  That was the issue.  Would have spent hours if you hadn't suggested looking for that

Comment: I gave an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `beginRefreshing()` was not called before the user pulled to refresh. If `refreshControl.isRefreshing` is `true` then the selector does not get called upon "pull to refresh".

A simple test:

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.refreshData), for: .valueChanged)
    tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // sets refreshControl.isRefreshing to true
    // before the user initiates it
    refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
}
```

Then the user pulls to refresh. Because `refreshControl.isRefreshing` is `true` the selector will not get called. If you remove `refreshControl.beginRefreshing()`in `viewDidAppear`, the selector will get called:

```
@objc func refreshData() {
    print("refresh initiated")
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning your `UIRefreshControl` into the `refreshControl` property of `UITableView` like this:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    tableView.refreshControl = refresher
} else {
    tableView.addSubview(refresher)
}
```

Note that this requires iOS 10.0 or higher, but we're soon getting iOS 12.0 so I don't think you should support iOS lower than 10.0

Comment: Have you tried using `UITableViewController` instead of placing a `UITableView` inside your `UIViewController` ?